# Refactorings fail in Eclipse with ADT when there are library projects

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a couple of non-android projects, one android library project and one android app project that depends on all other projects. Consequently, in the android app project I have a virtual MyLibrary_src source folder.

For some reason, when I'm doing refactoring in the library project, Eclipse partially executes it, but then fails with generic undo/abort dialog. I've found out that when I close the app project, refactorings complete without any problem. I suspect that the virtual source folder may be to blame, but I'm not sure.

Does anybody know how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ADT v14 the problem fixed itself.